# How to run an async WCF service in the cloud in a serverless, auto scaling manner

Tags: wcf, async-await, cloud, autoscaling

I need to run the services in a "auto-scaling" manner. ie. as load increases, I need it to create more of these services. I can use a cloud based load balancer to handle the routing of the messages from 1 to many instances.

Would hosting this in IIS (and somehow doing the port sharing etc) work?

Comment: Do you need to scale instances or servers?

Comment: I'd rather not have any servers if possible, so instances on serverless would be the preferred method